# there are unresolved merge conflict Issue

Tags: git, git-extensions

I have branch on git extensions every time I want to push code he show message that there is conflict
[image]

but there is no conflict

[image]

how can I push my code?

Comment: Try to do it with command line.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I had the same problem after updating my git installation to version 2.36.
Because `git status` showed the following hint in the command window:

> core.useBuiltinFSMonitor will be deprecated soon; use core.fsmonitor instead

I replaced in my system wide git configuration:

```
[core]
   useBuiltinFSMonitor = true
```

with

```
[core]
   fsmonitor = true
```

and the error disapeared.

[see my comment on git Extension issue 1653](https://github.com/gitextensions/gitextensions/issues/1653#issuecomment-1117379520)

Comment: Can confirm. I upgraded to 2.36 also. Same warning about useBuiltinFSMonitor, same spurious banner of merge conflicts in GitExtensions, same resolution -- it went away when I configured 'core.fsmonitor' instead.

Answer (score 0):

I just wasted my entire morning on this after updating git to 2.36; I did not get the warning that Martin got so didn't have any hints. I also had completely empty repos in the UI - no branches, no commits which was ... not good for my blood pressure.

Before I saw Martin's answer I just reinstalled the version I had before (2.33) again and that works fine; sticking with that for now.

Answer (score 0):

Try running this command:

```
git config --global --add safe.directory *
```

To me worked!

I used this [thread](https://github.com/gitextensions/gitextensions/issues/1653)